# Set Debian control file properties when deploying to Artifactory

Tags: maven, debian, artifactory, maven-deploy-plugin

I'm building a binary Debian archive with Maven, using `org.vafer.jdeb` plugin to create the .deb and `maven-deploy-plugin` plugin to deploy the archive on Artifactory.

The archive is correctly built (with `control` file and its mandatory fields). Nevertheless, when deployed to Artifactory, properties as `deb.distribution`, `deb.component`, `deb.architecture`, etc... are not set ; the archive can't be found.

Any idea on how to set the properties ?

Answer (score 2):

Can you please specify to which repository type are you deploying?

Since this is a .deb file, in order for Artifactory to produce the right metadata for it, you will need to use [Debian repositories](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Debian+Repositories). Since you are deploying using Maven, it sounds like you deploy the artifacts to a [Maven repository](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Maven+Repository) which could cause the metadata to be calculated differently.

I recommend maybe adding a promotion step to copy/move these files from the Maven repository to a Debian repository and check whether this step adds the properties.

I hope this helps and clarifies further.